# How to draw border around a UILabel?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uilabel

Is there a way for UILabel to draw a border around itself? This is useful for me to debug the text placement and to see the placement and how big the label actually is.

Answer (score 278, accepted):

You can set label's border via its underlying CALayer property:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

myLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor
myLabel.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
```

Swift 5:

```
myLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
myLabel.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
```

Comment: Compiler complaints that there is no definition of borderColor and borderWidth within CALayer.

Comment: they're available only starting SDK 3.0 :( If you want just a quick solution for debugging purpose you can set semitransparent colored background for your label.

Comment: If the compiler complains then you probably forgot to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Comment: Make sure you set the border width, because I guess it defaults to zero, and you won't see it if you don't set it.

Comment: @Vladimir This solution is adding the border to all the sides of the label. Can we add the border only the right side of the label ???

Comment: @chinthakad, no. I think you'll need custom label subclass with custom drawing for that

Comment: In Swift the first line would read: `myLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor`

Answer (score 77):

Here are some things you can do with `UILabel` and its borders.

[image]

Here is the code for those labels:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label4: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label5: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label6: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // label 1
        label1.layer.borderWidth = 1.0

        // label 2
        label2.layer.borderWidth = 5.0
        label2.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

        // label 3
        label3.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        label3.layer.cornerRadius = 8

        // label 4
        label4.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

        // label 5
        label5.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        label5.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        label5.layer.masksToBounds = true

        // label 6
        label6.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        label6.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        label6.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        label6.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Note that in Swift there is no need to import `QuartzCore`.

**See also**

- [Border, rounded corners, and shadow on a `CALayer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34984063/3681880)
- [Explanation of `masksToBounds`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34983655/3681880)
- [Using a border with a Bezier path for a layer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34659468/3681880)
- [How to do transforms on a `CALayer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34438890/3681880)

Comment: How were you able to get those paddings? My text is touching the borders...

Comment: @eestein, I think I just dragged the label size bigger in the Interface Builder. Or I might have set size constraints on them.

Answer (score 19):

Swift version:

```
myLabel.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
myLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
```

For Swift 3:

```
myLabel.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
myLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
```

Comment: it will be `myLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor!`

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 3/4 with @IBDesignable**

---

While almost all the above solutions work fine but I would suggest an `@IBDesignable` custom class for this.

```
@IBDesignable
class CustomLabel: UILabel {

    /*
    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.white {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 2.0 {
        didSet {
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

UILabel properties borderColor,borderWidth,cornerRadius in Swift 4

```
@IBOutlet weak var anyLabel: UILabel!
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        anyLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        anyLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2
        anyLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        anyLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the info from this answer  in my PaddedLabel with Border solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67317976/826946. Also gave a link back to here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this repo: [GSBorderLabel](https://github.com/JJSaccolo/GSBorderLabel)

It's quite simple:

```
GSBorderLabel *myLabel = [[GSBorderLabel alloc] initWithTextColor:aColor
                                                     andBorderColor:anotherColor
                                                     andBorderWidth:2];
```

Comment: This deals with border around the actual characters in the text, the question is talking about borders around the rectangle the text is contained in.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Swift 4:

yourLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor

Answer (score 0):

it really depends on how many boarder use in your view , sometimes , just add a UIVIEW which the size is a bit bigger to create the border . the method is faster than produce a view

Answer (score 0):

Using an NSAttributedString string for your labels attributedText is probably your best bet. [Check out this example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36870324/1541526)