# set label border in iphone

Tags: ios, uilabel, border

How can I set label's border which is dynamically generated (Not from Interface Builder)?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311591/how-to-draw-border-around-a-uilabel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw border around a UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311591/how-to-draw-border-around-a-uilabel)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

you can do it by

```
Label.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
Label.layer.borderWidth = 4.0;
```

before this you need to import a  framework QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h

Answer (score 3):

Swift version

[image]

**Set label border**

```
label.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
```

**Set border color**

```
label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
```

**Use rounded corners**

```
label.layer.cornerRadius = 8
```

**Make background color stay within rounded corners**

```
label.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to subclass your label and override the drawRect: method to draw or a border or whatever you like:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    CGContextStrokeRect(context, self.bounds);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can by default with `UILabel`. You might want to consider using a read-only (field.editing = NO) `UITextField` and setting it's borderStyle (which can be done programmatically using a `UITextBorderStyle`). That may be a little 'heavy' though. Another option may be to sub-class `UILabel` to draw your border.

Alternatively, and depending on your needs this may be better, use the backing `CALayer` and draw a border using it's borderColor and borderWidth properties.