# label.layer.borderColor = .... not working (Xcode 4.3.2)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uilabel

I am working in a class that is a subclass of UITableViewCell and have firstLabel and secondLabel properties declared in .h and being @synthesize in .m.  When I go to format the UILabels programmatically, I try to set the border around the firstLabel.  From the answer given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311591/how-to-draw-border-around-a-uilabel), I tried to do the same in my project.

```
firstLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
```

The problem is that it won't recognize it, after I type firstLabel.layer. and hit 'esc' (to get the list of completions) Xcode comes up with nothing.  What is the problem?

Note: if I type

```
firstLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

it works just fine and behaves as expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to import the QuartzCore header.  `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

(And don't forget to add the QuartzCore library as well or you will get a linker error when you try to build).

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Sadly now my UITableView is rendering quite slowly, got any suggestions there?

Comment: Pretty vague, it would warrant an entirely new question with info about your code that makes your cells.  A blanket statement, though, is *do less work in cellForRowAtIndex*

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Will try to work on my own first, then possibly submit a question later on.

Answer (score 5):

Did you set border width?

Like this:

```
[firstLabel.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
```