# how to change the shape of UIView

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiview

Is it possible to create a UIView with rounded edges ?

Comment: Mostly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510382/how-do-i-create-a-round-cornered-uilabel-on-the-iphone; the question's not exactly the same, but the answer implies UIViews only (since UILabels are UIViews).

Comment: Oh, also, exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509547/uiview-with-rounded-corners.

Answer (score 1):

From the other stackoverflow questions listed above...

3.0 and Later

iPhone OS 3.0 and later supports the cornerRadius property on the CALayer class. Every view has a CALayer instance that you can manipulate. This means you can get rounded corners in one line now:

```
view.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
```

You will need to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` and link to the QuartzCore framework to get access to CALayer's headers and properties.

Answer (score -1):

You can subclass UIView and override its drawBounds routine to draw its edges rounded, but the bounds of any UIView or subclass will always be a rectangle.

Comment: There is nothing about drawBounds method in documentation