# How to use rounded corner label in iphone, UILabel Round Corners

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using some labels in a view. I want to make rounded corner label in my iphone application. I use following code to do this but it's not work. I got have some errors to use that properties.

```
label.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
label.layer.borderWidth = 4.0;
label.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
```

Comment: How about putting an rounded corner image as background of the uilabel??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a round cornered UILabel on the iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510382/how-do-i-create-a-round-cornered-uilabel-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hard to know for sure what you're asking as you didn't include the errors you're getting. Have you added the `QuartzCore` framework to your project and `#import <QuartzCore/CALayer.h>` to the file modifying the layer? If that's not it, add the errors and more info to your question.

EDIT: you can also `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` as suggested in the comments. `QuartzCore.h` includes `CALayer.h` along with the rest of the `QuartzCore` components.

Comment: +1) importing #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> will remove all these type of errors.

Comment: @mohit You should accept XJones answer. Nobody will solve your problem if you not are ready to give them the credit for it.

Answer (score 20):

I was facing the same problem, using a UILabel with backgroundColor in a cell, and added this to work correctly :

```
label.layer.cornerRadius=8.0;
label.clipsToBounds=YES;
```

Comment: Should be cell.offLimitsLabel.clipsToBounds=true

Answer (score 13):

Just add `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in your .m file

and suppose you have a `UILabel *myLabel;`

just do `[myLabel.layer setCornerRadius:20];` //value '20' can be changed according to your wish :)

Comment: you can vote up or mark as correct answer. it will be good for other people who have same problem like yours, and can refer your SO post.Thank you

Comment: Just one tip (I had to add this line to make it work): myLabel.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

Answer (score 5):

This simple code enough for **RoundLabel**

```
LabelName.layer.cornerRadius = LableName.frame.size.height/2;
LabelName.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a view with rounded corners and add the label to that view.