# Rounded labels in Interface Builder...?

Tags: objective-c, ios, interface-builder, xcode4.3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I create a round cornered UILabel on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510382/how-do-i-create-a-round-cornered-uilabel-on-the-iphone)
>   [how to use rounded corner label in iphone,UILabel Round Corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530115/how-to-use-rounded-corner-label-in-iphone-uilabel-round-corners)

Still pretty much getting started with Xcode and Interface Builder. I made a UI screen with several 'label' fields to display random data. But when I change the label color from the screen background color, it looks awful because they're perfect squares. Is there a way to round the corners for labels?

Thanks!

Comment: I just looked at that. Dumb question: where do I type in that code?

Comment: This question will make more sense if the question really was about achieving rounded corners directly in Interface Builder, which is possible an not a duplicate of any of the questions on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/510630/994466):

> iPhone OS 3.0 and later supports the cornerRadius property on the CALayer class. Every view has a CALayer instance that you can manipulate. This means you can get rounded corners in one line now:

That post has a pretty detailed description of how to implement this behavior.

Comment: I just looked at that. Dumb question: where do I type in that code?

Comment: You'll need to connect the label to your view by creating an IBOutlet (in your .h file) and synthesizing it (in your .m file). I would do the configuration in the ViewController's viewDidLoad.