# uilabel text in round

Tags: iphone, uilabel

*this is my code but dont get the label in round*

//code is here

```
UILabel * lblWish= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x+25,318, 290, 100)];
lblWish.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( M_PI/90);
lblWish.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
[lblWish setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Dadhand" size:38]];
lblWish.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
lblWish.numberOfLines = 2;//Dynamic
lblWish.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
lblWish.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.4];
lblWish.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
lblWish.text = [ArylblWish objectAtIndex:i]

[self.view addSubview:lblWish];
```

Comment: what do you mean by "the label in round"?

Comment: Add quartzcore framework in your project and set Label CornerRadius to make it round.

Comment: See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510382/how-do-i-create-a-round-cornered-uilabel-on-the-iphone

Comment: i wont to label in round shape. so is this possible by programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want corner in round.
you need to add `QuartzCore Framework` and after add this code:
`lblWish.layer.cornerRadius=50;`