# How to round edges of UILabel with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have looked in the attributes of labels in Xcode 6.3 but I have not found out how to round the edges in the same way that you can round the edges of a text field.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a round cornered UILabel on the iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510382/how-do-i-create-a-round-cornered-uilabel-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Assuming you have added a `backgroundColor` to your label otherwise there would be no way to tell if it had edges, you can use QuartzCore to round the edges of a label.

```
import QuartzCore

yourLabel.layer.backgroundColor  = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
yourLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5
yourLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: yourLabel.layer.masksToBounds must be set to true.

Answer (score 209):

The trick is to set `maskToBounds` to true. Then your modifications to `cornerRadius` will be visible.

```
label.layer.masksToBounds = true
label.layer.cornerRadius = 5
```

Comment: **"label.layer.masksToBounds = true"** is an important code, if you apply corner radius to a label and if it dosen't work than adding this will definitely add the corner radius to a particular label.. So this should be the correct answer.. **And Thank You @spencer.sm!!**

Comment: Correct Answer!

Answer (score 35):

Use label layer corner radius to do that,

```
mylabel.layer.cornerRadius = yourvalue
```

if you don't want to show shadow then add,

```
mylabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

it worked for me fine.

Comment: Note that this is now `clipToBounds` in Swift 3 and higher.

Comment: The `clipToBounds` property can also be enabled in Interface Builder (Storyboard) in the Attributes inspector of the Label, under the Drawing section of the View.

Comment: @JamesHeald NO, clipToBounds is for UIView, and masksToBounds is for CALayer.

Answer (score 25):

You can give `cornerRadius` and border like this.

For Swift 5, 4 and 3

```
MyLable.layer.masksToBounds = true
MyLable.layer.cornerRadius = 6
MyLable.layer.borderWidth = 2
MyLable.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
```

For Objective-C

```
[MyLable.layer setMasksToBounds:TRUE];
[MyLable.layer setCornerRadius:6];
[MyLable.layer setBorderWidth:2];
[MyLable.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
```

Answer (score 17):

Select your `UILabel`

In your inspector, add `layer.masksToBounds` and `layer.cornerRadius`

[image: Easy way to achieve rounded corners for label]

Less code to handle in your classes

Comment: This is a good solution to assign the property in design time without code

Answer (score 14):

A way to round the corners of any `CALayer` is to modify `layer.cornerRadius`. By default that will affect only the background colour and any layer border you've applied. You can also enable `clipsToBounds` to clip the pixel contents.

When a view, such as a `UILabel` draws itself, it draws itself to the pixel contents of a layer. You can grab `view.layer` to access the layer.

So you can set that layer's corner radius to affect the background colour of the view. You can also enable `clipsToBounds` to crop any content within the view. Provided the view itself isn't drawing too close to the edge, that should achieve what you want. It should be correct for labels.

Comment: Great answer! Basically it means you have to add this line:    L.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor() ; L.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0 ; L.clipsToBounds = true  // where L is your UILabel

Comment: Well not really - you absolutely would just subclass it !

Answer (score 3):

Swift:

```
//round shape corner radius set
self.lblName.layer.masksToBounds = true
self.lblName.layer.cornerRadius = self.lblName.bounds.width / 2

//custom shape corner radius set
self.lblName.layer.masksToBounds = true
self.lblName.layer.cornerRadius = 12
```

Answer (score 2):

> Works fine in Xcode 8.1.2 with Swift 3, Tested during AUGUST 2017

"cornerRadius" is the key property to set the rounded edges, where if you are using the same style for all the labels in your application, I would recommend for an extension method.

**Code:**

```
  // extension Class
extension UILabel {

    // extension user defined Method
    func setRoundEdge() {
        let myGreenColor = (UIColor(red: -0.108958, green: 0.714926, blue: 0.758113, alpha: 1.0))
        //Width of border
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        //How much the edge to be rounded
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0

        // following properties are optional
        //color for border
        self.layer.borderColor = myGreenColor.cgColor
        //color for text
        self.textColor = UIColor.red
        // Mask the bound
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        //clip the pixel contents
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Why Extension method?**

Create a Swift file and add the following code, which has the Extention method to the "UILabel" class, where this method is user defined but will work for all the label in your application and will help to maintain consistency and clean code, if you change any style in future require only in the extension method.

Answer (score 2):

You create an extension for UIView with IBInspectable

```
extension UIView {

@IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
    get {
        return layer.cornerRadius
    }
    set {
        layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
    }
}

@IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat {
    get {
        return layer.borderWidth
    }
    set {
        layer.borderWidth = newValue
    }
}

@IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
    get {
        return UIColor(cgColor: layer.borderColor!)
    }
    set {
        layer.borderColor = newValue?.cgColor
    }
 }
}
```

[image]