# Customizing UIButton

Tags: iphone, ios, colors, uibutton

I have seen in the in-built apps for iphone that there is a red delete UIButton. My question is, how do I change the color of the button. Usually there is a 'tint' attribute in the attributes inspector but there is not when using a UIbutton.
Is there any way to programmatically change the color?
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make buttons with colors by using the layer of the button. First add the QuartzCore framework to your project. Then add `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` into your view class. To make a red button do this

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
[myButton setFrame: CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 300.0f, 44.0f)];
[[myButton layer] setBackgroundColor: [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
[self addSubview: myButton];
[myButton release];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Put it into the init method of the view in which the button should appear.

Comment: I did not down vote this. This is a good implementation, although i prefer drawing an image myself as I get more user friendliness... (like rounded edges) :)
I have a question though. What is the difference of putting code like this in the init method of a View Controller rather in the viewDidLoad method? is there a difference?

Comment: Today I would prefer to put it into viewDidLoad. Therefore it does not occupy memory until it is needed.

Comment: cornerRadius = 8, [button addTarget:self action:@selector(touch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown]; is a nice addition. the touch event can change the layers backgroundColor for a nice affect...

Answer (score 3):

That tint color for an `UIButton` is only available for the [`UIGlassButton`](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/UIGlassButton) which is an <strike>private</strike> undocumented API. Some solutions around using the <strike>private</strike> undocumented API are to use images or try [drawing your own gradient](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/drawing-gloss-gradients-in-coregraphics.html).

Resources:

[UIGlassButton in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380736/uiglassbutton-in-iphone)

http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/drawing-gloss-gradients-in-coregraphics.html

https://github.com/dermdaly/ButtonMaker

Answer (score 3):

If your button is of type `UIButtonTypeRoundedRect` instead of `UIButtonTypeCustom`, setting the background color on the layer doesn't work.

Try this, it works for me.

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = self.buttonAddToOrder.bounds;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor redColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor redColor] CGColor], nil];
gradient.cornerRadius = 10;

[myButton.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

Hope this may help.