# How can I create a big, red UIButton with iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

Using iOS, how would I go about creating a red "delete" button similar to the one used when deleting contacts on the iPhone?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372731/how-can-i-set-a-button-background-color-on-iphone) is very close to yours, and contains a couple of ways of generating such a colored button.

Comment: I've done this recently also, and creating this button for it ([and some Monotouch example code](http://www.yetanotherchris.me/home/2010/10/10/monotouch-tips-and-snippets.html) for any monotouchers): ![alt text](http://www.yetanotherchris.me/storage/downloads/uiglassbutton-template.png) It has less of a bevel which works better on any background, but doesn't match the iPhone `UIGlassButton` exactly.

Comment: I've added some button images available freely under the MIT licence to my site, which more closely match the iOS glass buttons. (but this forum won't let me post images b/c I'm new) To download them and for sample code, see: http://www.geneticmistakes.com/articles/1000/stretchable-dynamic-images-for-buttons

Comment: Here is the entire built-in iOS assets: https://github.com/pixelfreak/iOS-UI-Assets

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You first start with a stretchable image:

[alt text http://grab.by/4lP](http://grab.by/4lP)

Then you make a button with the stretched image as the background and apply text.

```
UIButton *sampleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[sampleButton setFrame:CGRectMake(kLeftMargin, 10, self.view.bounds.size.width - kLeftMargin - kRightMargin, 52)];
[sampleButton setTitle:@"Button Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[sampleButton setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20]];
[sampleButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"redButton.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[sampleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:sampleButton];
```

Obviously, you will need to adjust the frame origin and size to match your app, as well as the target, selector, and title.

Comment: Good solution. Just one codefix: you forgot the @-sign for the string in -[UIImage imageNamed:].

Comment: Note: Anthony's Question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276099/a-big-green-uiimage-anyone/2276272

Comment: Excellent post - thanks for the free image, I'll be using it :)

Comment: I believe this is now out of date as 'setFont' for UIButton has been deprecated. Still a good answer.

Comment: `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:` has also been deprecated in 5.0, in favor of `resizableImageWithCapInsets:`

Answer (score 62):

I've also made some buttons...retina and non-retina versions

If you want to use them in a Cell just use the following code in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
UIButton *sampleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[sampleButton setFrame:[cell.contentView frame]];
[sampleButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.bounds.size.width-20, 44)];
[sampleButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_red.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell addSubview:sampleButton];
```

[image: Green Button Normal]

[image: Red Button Normal]

[image: Grey Button Normal]

[image: Green Button Retina]
[image: Red Button Retina]
[image: Grey Button Retina]

Comment: Do you have any of these with a transparent background? When I put them in a view with a non-white background, it looks screwy... know what I mean?

Comment: @Hisoka: sampleButton.alpha = 0.5;

Comment: Very nice. Are these taken from iPhone's GUI?

Answer (score 22):

I think those ones are better (and **they look fine on retina display** too) :

[image]
[image]

.png generated from this very nice .psd file : http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/2010/08/12/iphone-4-gui-psd-retina-display/

And then use it as a strechable image for the background of your `UIButton`:

`UIImage* greenButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"UIButton_green.png"]; 
UIImage *newImage = [greenButton stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:greenButton.size.width/2 topCapHeight:greenButton.size.height/2];
[callButton setBackgroundImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: Note that using these in an app violates the original author's license.

Comment: Please note that the link has now expired and you get a "page not found", obviously this is not your fault but I thought you could maybe update the link with a new one if you have one.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the simplest way to do it is to snag [this iPhone GUI Photoshop file](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/?p=447) that contains lots of UI elements in PSD layers, then change the tint of the large button in Photoshop and save it as a PNG.

One advantage of doing it this way is that you can also create versions for button selected and/or highlight state and assign the images to a standard UIButton.

Comment: one disadvantage is you need to keep tons of large images in your bundle, and they will not fit the screen on a different rotation

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate section in your grouped table view, give that section only one row, and set that cell's background image to a red gradient image. You'll have to recreate that image on your own, though.

Comment: while this works, it is not a customizable as my presented solution as in order to get special highlighting or states, you would need to implement custom logic that Apple already includes in the UIButton class

Answer (score 0):

I would like to contribute a solution which does not use images but which gives the same look as the 'delete' button in Contacts. 
In the below example I will use assume a UITableView with **grouped**, static cells, designed in storyboard. Make one of the sections have only a single cell. That cell will be the 'delete' button. Give the cell a red background color (f.e. Red 221, Green 0, Blue 2)

What we will do is add two GradientLayers to the cell. The first will cover the upper half of the cell. The second will cover the lower half.

Add QuartzCore to your implementation file:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Start with making an outlet to this cell:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellDelete;
```

Create a method in which the cell will be formatted:

```
- (void)formatCellDelete
{
    // Top Gradient //
    CAGradientLayer *gradientTop = [CAGradientLayer layer];

    // Make a frame for the layer based on the size of the cells contentView
    // Make it half the height
    // The width will be -20 so the gradient will not overflow
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _cellDelete.contentView.frame.size.width - 20, _cellDelete.contentView.frame.size.height / 2);
    gradientTop.frame = frame;

    gradientTop.cornerRadius = 8;

    UIColor* topColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.75f];
    UIColor* bottomColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.0f];
    gradientTop.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[topColor CGColor], (id)[bottomColor CGColor], nil];

    [_cellDelete.contentView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [_cellDelete.contentView.layer insertSublayer:gradientTop atIndex:0];



    // Bottom Gradient //
    CAGradientLayer *gradientBottom = [CAGradientLayer layer];

    // Make a frame for the layer based on the size of the cells contentView
    // Make it half the height
    // The width will be -20 so the gradient will not overflow
    frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _cellDelete.contentView.frame.size.width - 20, _cellDelete.contentView.frame.size.height / 2);
    // And move to bottom
    frame.origin.y = frame.size.height;
    gradientBottom.frame = frame;

    topColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.05f]; //0.20
    bottomColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.0f];
    gradientBottom.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[topColor CGColor], (id)[bottomColor CGColor], nil];

    [_cellDelete.contentView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [_cellDelete.contentView.layer insertSublayer:gradientBottom atIndex:0];


    // Define a selected-backgroundColor so the cell changes color when the user tabs it
    UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [bgColorView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(float)(0.502) green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.000]];
    bgColorView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    [_cellDelete setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
}
```

The above will give your cell the glass-look like the 'delete' button in Contacts.
But we also want it to change color when the user taps it. This is what the last piece of code  in the above method will do. It will set a different view with a darker color as the selectedBackgroundView.

After tapping the cell will stay selected and will keep its dark color. To automatically deselect the cell we do the following:

Start with a constant which defines the section nr of your delete cell:

```
static NSInteger const SECTION_DELETE = 1;
```

Now implement the `(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method (defined in UITableViewDelegate):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if(indexPath.section == SECTION_DELETE){

        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }


    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     ￼ *detailViewController = [[￼ alloc] initWithNibName:@"￼" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */

}
```