# Where can I get fancy red and green UIButtons kind of like "End Call", etc?

Tags: iphone, button, sdk, uibutton

Is there any resource for an iPhone developer who wants bright red and green buttons in their app? I mean, as in pre-cut buttons? The closest I've found are the Photoshop templates and those are a bit difficult to cut out just right.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427818/iphone-sdk-creating-a-big-red-uibutton) seems to provide a solution to a similar question, helpful to many people.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get custom buttons is via Core Animation (even if you're not actually animating).  See [this site](http://www.cimgf.com/2010/01/28/fun-with-uibuttons-and-core-animation-layers/) for a detailed explanation with code.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a blog entry demonstrating how to make shiny buttons with `CAGradientLayer`: [Shiny iPhone Buttons Without Photoshop](http://undefinedvalue.com/2010/02/27/shiny-iphone-buttons-without-photoshop)