# UIBarButtonItem with UIButton as CustomView - from UIButton, how to access the UIBarButtonItem its in?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I have a `UIBarButtonItem` with `UIButton` as custom view.

The `UIButton` has a `addTarget:action:` on it. In the action I present a popover. I'm currently presenting from the `sender.frame` (the `UIButton`'s Frame)  I want to Present from the `UIBarButtonItem` instead.

How can I access the `UIBarButtonItem` from the `UIButton`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have set your `UIButton` as the `customView` of a `UIBarButtonItem`, or a child of the custom view, then you can walk up the view hierarchy from your button until you find the `UIToolbar` or `UINavigationBar` that contains the button, then search the bar's items for the one whose custom view is the button (or an ancestor of the button).

Here's my completely untested code for doing that.  You would call `[[self class] barButtonItemForView:myButton]` to get the item containing your button.

```
+ (BOOL)ifBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)item containsView:(UIView *)view storeItem:(UIBarButtonItem **)outItem {
    UIView *customView = item.customView;
    if (customView && [view isDescendantOfView:customView]) {
        *outItem = item;
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}

+ (BOOL)searchBarButtonItems:(NSArray *)items forView:(UIView *)view storeItem:(UIBarButtonItem **)outItem {
    for (UIBarButtonItem *item in items) {
        if ([self ifBarButtonItem:item containsView:view storeItem:outItem])
            return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

+ (UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItemForView:(UIView *)view {
    id bar = view;
    while (bar && !([bar isKindOfClass:[UIToolbar class]] || [bar isKindOfClass:[UINavigationBar class]])) {
        bar = [bar superview];
    }
    if (!bar)
        return nil;

    UIBarButtonItem *item = nil;

    if ([bar isKindOfClass:[UIToolbar class]]) {
        [self searchBarButtonItems:[bar items] forView:view storeItem:&item];
    }

    else {
        UINavigationItem *navItem = [bar topItem];
        if (!navItem)
            return nil;
        [self ifBarButtonItem:navItem.backBarButtonItem containsView:view storeItem:&item]
        || [self ifBarButtonItem:navItem.leftBarButtonItem containsView:view storeItem:&item]
        || [self ifBarButtonItem:navItem.rightBarButtonItem containsView:view storeItem:&item]
        || ([navItem respondsToSelector:@selector(leftBarButtonItems)]
            && [self searchBarButtonItems:[(id)navItem leftBarButtonItems] forView:view storeItem:&item])
        || ([navItem respondsToSelector:@selector(rightBarButtonItems)]
            && [self searchBarButtonItems:[(id)navItem rightBarButtonItems] forView:view storeItem:&item]);
    }

    return item;
}
```

Comment: You the man!  I have not been able to test the NavigationItems as I'm using a UIToolBar. This works very well! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

First of all, why do you need to access the `UIBarButtonItem`?

Then, to create a `UIBarButtonItem` with a custom view I suggest you to create a category extension like the following (in this case the custom view is a `UIButton`).

```
//UIBarButtonItem+Extension.h    
+ (UIBarButtonItem*)barItemWithImage:(UIImage*)image title:(NSString*)title target:(id)target action:(SEL)action;

//UIBarButtonItem+Extension.m    
+ (UIBarButtonItem*)barItemWithImage:(UIImage*)image title:(NSString*)title target:(id)target action:(SEL)action
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    button.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem* barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

    return [barButtonItem autorelease];    
}
```

and the use it like this (first import `UIBarButtonItem+Extension.h`):

```
UIBarButtonItem* backBarButtonItem = [UIBarButtonItem barItemWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YoutImageName"] title:@"YourTitle" target:self action:@selector(doSomething:)];
```

where the selector it's a method that is implemented inside the class (the target) that uses that bar button item.

Now inside the `doSomething:` selector you could the following:

```
- (void)doSomething:(id)sender

    UIButton* senderButton = (UIButton*)sender;    
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:senderButton.bounds inView:senderButton...];
}
```

A category in this case it's useful to not duplicate code. Hope it helps.

P.S. I'm not using ARC but same considerations can be also applied.

**Edit:**

An easy solution to access the bar button item could be the following:

1. Subclass a `UIButton`
2. Create within it a property of type `UIBarButtonItem` (a weak one to avoid retaincycle)
3. Inject the bar button item in the `UIButton` when you create it.

Maybe it could work, but I will prefer the first one.

Comment: I have something Similar to your code, though I did a Subclass of UIBarButtonItem as the Look and feel of the button is pretty custom.  The problem is the ` [popover presentPopoverFromRect:senderButton.bounds inView:senderButton...];'  This requires quite a bit of work to re position the popover upon rotation, keyboard, etc. Having the popover be presented from a UIBarButtonItem eliminates all of that and always anchors to the UIBarButtonItem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that you need the UIButton. If what you're doing is dispatching an action, or even customizing the button with an image, the `UIBarButtonItem` should suffice.

If what you're after is to grab the frame from the `UIButton` in order to achieve the presentation, I think you might be better served to simply estimate the position of the `UIBarButtonItem`. This shouldn't be too difficult, especially if it's one or the other of your `UINavigationItem`'s `leftBarButtonItem` or `rightBarButtonItem`.

I'm generally for the KISS (Keep It Simple, Stupid!) rule of thumb. Even Apple does this... when you launch an app from Springboard, the app always expands from the center of the screen, not from the app's icon.

Just a suggestion.

EDIT

OK, I just read the [UIPopoverController reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html) (I've never used one). I think what you want is `presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:permittedArrowDirections:animated:` and to pass in your BBI as the first parameter. The reason that method exists is to solve your problem - BBI's have no frame because they're not subclasses NSView. Apple knows that you want to do this kind of thing, and provides this method. Also, I think if you use this method, that your autorotation will work as well. I may be wrong about this, give it a shot.

As far as your customized layout is concerned, I think if you replicate it in a UIView and make the BBI custom with that, you will do better. This is of course up to you.

Either way, you get a reference to the BBI by either connecting it as an IBOutlet with your NIB, or by saving a reference to it when you create it in code. Then just pass that reference to the popover method I described above. I think this might work for you.

MOAR

The BBI is just a member of your class - an iVar with a strong reference property on it, perhaps linked up as an IBOutlet to your NIB. Then you can access it from whatever method you want in the class.

Example: (not sure that I have the popover controller memory management right)

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
   UIBarButtonItem *item;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIBarButtonItem *item;

@end



@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize item;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
   // assuming item isn't in your NIB
   item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemPlus target:self action:@selector(doit)];
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item;
}

-(void)doit {
   UIPopoverController *popover = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:yourViewController] autorelease];
   [popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:self.item permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
   // or in the line above, replace self.item with self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
}

@end
```

Comment: The real problem is my Popover that is presented from the action of the UIButton. When I rotate the Screen, the popover is not anchored to the UIBarButtonItem, its anchored to the Frame of the sender of the action, which is the UIButton.  I needed the UIButton as my UIToolBar is Custom, the Buttons are 84x48 across the bottom, 3 buttons, flex space, 4 buttons.  The UIButton allows me to have the BartButtonItem have a Custom Graphic and Label in Specific Positions in the 84x48.

Comment: Since the Popovers that are presented from BarButtonItems don't have the positioning issue, I thought I could do a sender.superView on the UIButton and get the UIBarButtonItem.  instead I get the UIToolBar. I have the Position of the Button as a tag, can I just traverse the UIToolBar for the UIBarButtonItem?

Comment: Sorry about that. If you present your popover using the method I indicated above, `presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:permittedArrowDirections:animated:`, then the popover will automatically be repositioned as appropriate during device orientation changes.

Comment: Exactly! How do I get access to the UIBarButtonItem? The BarButtonItem I have is init'ed withCusomView, which is a UIButton. The UIButton has the addTarget on it. So when the button is pressed, it's the sender to the action. Once in the action, I'd love to get access to the UIBarButtonItem. The only way I've come up with is to subclass the UIButton, add a iVar for the UIBarButtonItem, and set it when I Init the button.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't real all of your edit. I'll have to see about using a UIView or UIImageView as my custom View vs. the UIbutton. I just liked the UIButton as it shades the images with highlights, selected, Normal, disabled. All of which I use a differ color to represent the state. I also added a UILabel as a sub view to the UIButton for a different placement of the title text. That text also dims when disabled.

Comment: I added the stuff under MOAR just now. If you use the UIButton, then you should still be able to maintain a reference to the BBI when you create it

Comment: I would need the `UIBarButtonItem` linked to the `UIButton` as I have , at the moment, 7 `UIBarButtonItem`s

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have added the UIButton aButton to UIBarButtonItem info_Button as following:

```
//Add a button on top of the UIBarButtonItem info_button
UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showInfo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
info_Button.customView = aButton;
```

Now, in showInfo, presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:info_Button(instead of presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender), this will pass the UIBarButtonItem info_button to make pop over works:

```
- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender
{   
    [self.flipsidePopoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:info_Button   permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// get the UIBarButtonItem from the UIButton that is passed in sender
UIToolbar *toolbar = (id)[sender superview];
UIBarButtonItem *ourButtonItem = [toolbar items][2];//pick the right index
[parkingPopOver_ presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:ourButtonItem permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```