# How to make a button look like this? (the iPhone's Timer App)

Tags: iphone, uitableview

[image]

To me, this looks like a UITableViewCell, but with rounded corners. I also want the behavior of my "button" to do behave the same way as in the timer App. How do I do it?

EDIT: By "button" I mean the one that says "When Timer Ends". again, to me it looks like a TableViewCell. Thanks for the speedy responses guys.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427818/iphone-sdk-creating-a-big-red-uibutton

Comment: sorry i wasn't clear, but I was referrening to the "button"/tableview cell that reads "When Timer Ends"

Comment: I think that you can embed a button into the cell....

Answer (score 2):

This question has already been asked: [see here for the tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427818/iphone-sdk-creating-a-big-red-uibutton).

**EDIT:** It looks like the "button" is actually a `UITableViewCell` (although it's hard to tell for sure).  For a tutorial on customizing table cells, [see here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html).

Comment: Thanks, I will more than likely need this, but I meant the other "button", a term I use loosely.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to achieve this is a combination of a UITableViewCell and a UIButton.

The UITableViewCell will give you the table-view-cell style, and the UIButton will allow you to select it as you would select a table view cell in a table view.

In order to be able to select the UIButton, place it in front of the UITableViewCell and reduce it's alpha level to something around 0.2-0.3.