# Delete Destructive Button like in UIActionSheet

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uiactionsheet

I need to create a button programmatically just like in the image

[image]

I know that this is a destructive button in UIActionSheet. Is there any way to use distructive button as a UIButton ?

Thanks,

Tariq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to set a destructive button as a `UIButton`,unless you create a custom button with a red gradient background image  like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427818/iphone-sdk-creating-a-big-red-uibutton)
You can create a red button like the methode specified above or like [THIS](http://www.cimgf.com/2010/01/28/fun-with-uibuttons-and-core-animation-layers/)

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of projects like this around the net

https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor

That use the private api to generate image files you can use with a standard UIButton. Nice little route around the problem.

Comment: Be careful before using that. It any lead to your app rejection at anytime and also your may break in future updates by apple.

Comment: @Madhup no you use that app to generate a bunch of .png files that you use in your app. No private api calls, just regular UIButtons.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way you can change the functionality of destructive Button except that you access the parts protected by apple (using private api).

You should also avoid changing the functionality as it would be against [user interface guidelines](http://www.upsidelearning.com/blog/index.php/2010/06/24/iphone-user-interface-guidelines-part-i/) and moreover it will get the users confused also.

Thanks,

Madhup