# How do I create a "delete" actionsheet in xcode?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet, confirmation

How do I create a delete confirmation like the one shown below?

[image]

Comment: Look up a UIActionSheet in the docs.

Comment: I've edited your title because the word "popver" refers to something else. (See the [UIPopoverController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html) class reference.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the same as shown in photo along with other button use the below [UIActionSheet blog tutorial](http://iphonetut.com/iphone_apps_-_interface_builder/102/uiactionsheet_tutorial_in_iphone) and if you want just standalone button follow the below SO post

[How can I create a big, red UIButton with the iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427818/iphone-sdk-creating-a-big-red-uibutton)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [UIActionSheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

You can create an ActionSheet like this

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
                                initWithTitle:@”YOUR_ACTION_SHEET_TITLE” 
                                delegate:self 
                                cancelButtonTitle:@”Cancel” 
                                destructiveButtonTitle:@”Erase Iphone” 
                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
[actionSheet release];//If you are not using ARC
```

You need to implement `UIActionSheetDelegate` method

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet 
            clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    if (buttonIndex == 0){
       //do your action
    }else if(buttonIndex == 1){
      // do your other action
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is an instance of a [UIActionSheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html). The red button is called the "destructive button" and the black button, the "cancel button".

Here is a demo:

```
UIActionSheet *actSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"The text to show on top. (Like the message about wiping the phone.)"delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete everything" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[actSheet ShowFromToolbar:self.toolbar];
[actSheet release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use InterfaceBuilder (or the equivalent editors in xCode4) to create the view. Write your view controller. Then animate the view to slide in from below using Core Animation.