# How to imitate a red gloss delete button in iphone/ipad contact?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

I want to have a green "OK" button and a red "Cancel" button in my app. The red one would look like:

[image]

I wonder if this can be done programmatically instead of taking screenshot -> photoshop crops -> set as a custom button in IB

Thanks!
Leo

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a big, red UIButton with the iPhone SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427818/how-can-i-create-a-big-red-uibutton-with-the-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like Jeff LaMarche's [Gradient Buttons](http://code.google.com/p/iphonegradientbuttons/) library for this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking at it right now. Compared to images, is this custom drawing going to be noticeably slow?

Comment: Well I'm sure it is some, but it's never been enough that I've noticed it.

Answer (score 2):

A little Googling would have thrown up this:

http://www.cimgf.com/2010/01/28/fun-with-uibuttons-and-core-animation-layers/

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/imageless-gradient-buttons

Answer (score 1):

Check out [UIKit-Artwork-Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor) in github. It allows you to play with the colors and save the resulting buttons ready for use.

Comment: I am currently using this approach. I guess it's  faster than draw rect with float point calculations.