# How can I make a UIButton look like a delete button (iphone/iPad)?

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I want to make my UIButton look like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this look? Is there a built in setting or will I just have to manually create it in photoshop?

Comment: Check this out: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/drawing-gloss-gradients-in-coregraphics.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a big, red UIButton with the iPhone SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427818/how-can-i-create-a-big-red-uibutton-with-the-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a uibutton of type custom, and provide an image for each state.

```
UIButton *myDeleteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[myDeleteButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_button_titlebar_delete.png"]    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myDeleteButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_button_titlebar_delete_on.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

So, yes, you'll need to use PhotoShop or some other imaging tool.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to just use an image for the background, like this one:

[image: red button gradient background image]

There's also a class called GMButton that is found [on github](https://github.com/progrmr/SDK_Utilities/tree/master/GM_Subclasses).  You can set the title, color, titleColor for each state.  Just use it in place of UIButton (it's a subclass of UIButton).  With it you can create buttons like these or these:

[image: screenshot of buttons]
[image]

For your Delete button, I would try this:

```
GMButton* button = [GMButton buttonWithFrame:CGRectMake(18,3,284,34)];

button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];

[button setTitle:@"Delete" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

It uses 3 layers to create the button.  A CAGradientLayer for the bevel, a CALayer for the color, and a CAGradientLayer for the highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

For UIButton, there is no built in setting to achieve this. You could either code it yourself with gradients, or create custom images for the button's states. The only built in option to get this button is via an UIActionSheet.