# How can I make a UIButton look like a delete button (iphone/iPad)? 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have an image view,on that there are programmatically created `UIButtons`. I want to delete these buttons through an `UIActionSheet`. is this possible in an iPad? Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to set a destructive button as a `UIButton`,unless you create a custom button with a red gradient background image  like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427818/iphone-sdk-creating-a-big-red-uibutton)

You can create a red button like the method specified above or like [THIS](http://www.cimgf.com/2010/01/28/fun-with-uibuttons-and-core-animation-layers/)

Comment: i am facing one problem,whenever i am deleting a particular button,everytime the last button is getting deleted.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

using these actionsheet delegate method you can delete that programmaticlly created button for eg:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
    switch(buttonIndex)
    {
        case 0:

        [button removefromsuperview];

    }
}
```