# iPhone Style Buttons

Tags: iphone, image

Is there a standard/accepted way of making image buttons the "iPhone" style? i.e. with the gloss highlight and rounded corners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372731/how-can-i-set-a-button-background-color-on-iphone/373572) provide some ways of doing this.  Also, I provide an example of a gloss gradient for drawing on a custom button view [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422066/gradients-on-uiview-and-uilabels-on-iphone/422208#422208).

Answer (score 1):

You may find the following links useful:

IPhone UI PSD: http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/?p=447

IPhone toolbar style icons : http://glyphish.com/

:)

Answer (score 1):

There are images you can download from Apple here

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/UICatalog/index.html

that are suitable for use as iPhone button backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done it is by using my own custom images.

If it's just one button, you can create an image for the whole button. If it's just the background, and you're going to re-use it with different button title text, you can create an appropriate smaller image, and use - stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight: (a method of UIImage for creating new images).

The graphics editor I use is Fireworks.

I've always seen it done this way by others, too. My designer friends use Photoshop.

Some of Apple's sample code (e.g. UICatalog) has background images you can use.