# Frame of UIButtonTypeRoundedRect

Tags: iphone

For UIButton i was using first UIButtonTypeCustom now i want to change it to RoundedRect but when i change UIButtonTypeCustom to UIButtonTypeRoundedRect it shows RoundedRect in white instead of color specified for it and plus it shows edges of rect buttonframe in back of roundedrect button. So i want to know how to fix this thing.

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30);

[myButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:1.0/12 saturation:2.0/3 brightness:4.0/10 alpha:1.0];

UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton];

[[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:button animated:YES];
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you tried `button.tintColor`?  That's what I use for UIBarButtonItems.  It may save you from having to use a custom view for the bar button item.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Coloration of UIButtons of type UIButtonTypeRoundedRect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088254/coloration-of-uibuttons-of-type-uibuttontyperoundedrect)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mmm... I afraid it is not possible to change the backgroundColor of your `UIButton` if it is `UIButtonTypeRoundedRect`.

My suggestion is to create a `UIButtonTypeCustom` and change its layer to mimic a `UIButtonTypeRoundedRect`.

Try this code:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

[myButton.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[myButton.layer setCornerRadius:10.0f];
[myButton.layer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
```