# How to set the background color of an UIButtonTypeRoundedRect Button?

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

I tried `tintColor = [UIColor redColor]` and it does the job, but it only show the expected color when the button is being pressed.

In [Coloration of UIButtons of type UIButtonTypeRoundedRect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088254/coloration-of-uibuttons-of-type-uibuttontyperoundedrect) they answer the same question but you need an image to implement it, **is there any way to do it without an image?**

- Here is what i want: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvNqn.png)
- Here is what i'm getting using images:  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2Aom.png)

Remember... **NO IMAGES!**

Comment: @ Balz, check my edited answer. that should take care of your issue. just remove the border frame if you don't want to use it so it will be just one color.

Comment: check the edit in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

well using an image is one way of doing it, but i guess you already clear that in your question that you do not wish to use an image. here is button that i created and colored programmatically.

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100,50);
[btn setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:128.0/255.0f green:0.0/255.0f blue:0.0/255.0f alpha:0.7]];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 120.0, 50.0);//width and height should be same value
btn.clipsToBounds = YES;

btn.layer.cornerRadius = 20;//half of the width
btn.layer.borderColor=[UIColor redColor].CGColor;
btn.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;

[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

you can change the `[UIColor ColorWithRed:` wo whatever you want or even use `[UIColor redColor]` or any other things you want to do with this.

here is a screen shot:

[image]

adding a background color to rounded button is not possible, change the type of the button to custom and then use quartz core to set a round button. so add that to your project and import it in the .m and it should work. hope this works for you man.

to change the button to something similar to the image you showed change the frame to :

```
btn.frame = CGRectMake(50.0, 100.0, 200.0, 50.0);
```

and change the radius to :

```
btn.layer.cornerRadius = 7;
```

that should do it.

Comment: Is there any way to make it look like [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uvNqn.png) ?

Comment: You can play with the size of the corner radius. Reduce it till you get the desired effect. Anything is possible with quartz core. Just play around with it and make something you like out of the code I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method to generate an `UIImage` from a `UIColor` and then set the returned image as the background of the button, for example:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);

    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}


UIImage *image = [self imageWithColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:151.0/255.0
                                                      green:36.0/255.0
                                                       blue:40.0/255.0
                                                      alpha:1.0]];
[self.button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.button.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0;
self.button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
self.button.layer.borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
self.button.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Using this I get

[image]

Comment: Hi, that produced [this](http://s12.postimg.org/u5d6ipep9/getting.png)... but i need something like [this](http://s22.postimg.org/3q0d9s6ap/Expected.png).

Comment: Yes, I see, I have edited my answer, check the button configuration

Comment: Is there any way to add a vertical gradient to the color of the button??... look at this button [image of button](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uvNqn.png) ... it has a darker red color in bottom and a lighter red color at the top.

Comment: yes, it is possible, create an image, subclass UIButton and override the draw method, or read all the solution from here https://www.google.es/search?q=gradient+background+uibutton

Comment: I have found this [article](http://www.raywenderlich.com/33330/core-graphics-tutorial-glossy-buttons), you should take a look to it

Answer (score 0):

here's how I should do it:

download a button image from the internet or create an image yourself, to make it look like you want it to look like. Photoshop might be your best shot for this. make sure you have a **transparent background** and save it as a .png.
then add it to your xcode project. to make the button:

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [btn setTitle:@"Use it!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
    btn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(position and size of your button);
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
```

yourImage.png needs to be replaced with the name of your image.

The `buttonAction` is the action your button performs when it's tapped. if you just add:

```
- (void) buttonAction
{

}
```

anywhere in your file, anything you added between those brackets will be performed.

Make sure the size of your button is the same as the size of your `CGRect`, to make sure it doesn't look stretched out or anything you don't want it to look like.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask them.

Hope this helped you