# Background color for subclassed UIButton?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton

I have a UIButton subclass that I initialize as:

```
MyButton *button = [MyButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

I want to set the background color of this button.

If I do the following in the view controller after creating the button:

```
MyButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor ...];
```

It works fine. But if I try to do the following within the `UIButton` subclass, either in `initWithFrame` or in `DrawRect:`

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor ...];
```

It simply does nothing. The button remains transparent.

The thing is, my logic is such that I really need to set the color inside the UIButton subclass, not in the calling code.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372731/how-can-i-set-a-button-background-color-on-iphone

Comment: in the drawRect, did you call [super drawRect]? if not try calling that and then do other things.

Comment: Yes, I always do [super drawRect]. As I said, no background color.

Answer (score 1):

`UIButton` is not meant to be subclassed. It is a class cluster and you almost certainly get it wrong (it may break now or in the future). The base method `buttonWithType:` also will never return an instance of your class, so you need to go to great lengths to make all your code work.

The *much* better way is to to make a factory method that uses `UIButton.buttonWithType:` and configures the button the way you need it.

Comment: How can we know that? Is there any apple ressource that explans which UI elements can be subclassed and which not?

Comment: Because there is no real documented init method on UIButton. We do need to call init, though. The most important properties is the buttonType, which is readonly - i.e. it must be set during creation. The behavior of the button depends heavily on it. The only way to set it, is to instantiate a new button by using the factory method '+buttonWithType:'. You are not guaranteed to get a working button - UIButton might be a somewhat abstract class, and there is no way to find out. Subclassing obviously works at the moment (as a "custom" button) just fine, but it *might* break in a heartbeat.

Answer (score 0):

Can you implement "Buttonwithtype" method in your subclass and write code there self.backgroundColor = [UIColor WhateverColor];

It should work. let me know.

Comment: Yes it worked, thank you. (I couldn't implement just buttonWithType because I needed the color - using a property would be too late - so I implemented buttonWithType: andBackgroundColor: and called [super buttonWithType]. I'm still wondering what's wrong with the straightforward solution.

Comment: Great.  May be it is because which ever method you wrote that doesn't call ? If this help then can you please mark it as answer? I am new to stackoverflow so I get some credits:) Thanks