# Make green color UIActionSheet button?

Tags: ios, customization, uiactionsheet

I know I can access a individual button on a actionSheet using a for loop to access the particular button in the action sheet I want, but the thing is, how would I make a green button?
I know each button acts almost identically to a UIButton so how should I go upon making one of my buttons in the action sheet green?

I just need some tips or help with this as it is the last part of my app that isn't done!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have needed customizations for UIActionSheets, sometimes I find methods to make it happen simply, but more often I end up having to set up a custom view on way or another.  I've added all manners of custom controls with:

```
[sheet addSubview: myCustomActionSheetController.view];
```

You might need to set the size as well.

Comment: Alright so if I end up using a custom actionsheet, how would I make a button green? Would I have to have my own green image?

Comment: I used the discussion in the following link, which suggests a UISegmentedControl.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372731/how-can-i-set-a-button-background-color-on-iphone

Comment: So there is no way to do this without using a custom action sheet? I don't really want to use a segmented control :[

Comment: No documented way, and undocumented ways(which I don't happen to know for this case) might get your app rejected.  The segmented control ends up looking like a standard button when it only has one segment.  If you really have to make it look like an actionsheet button, you can use a UIButton with a custom background as recommended in that same discussion.  UIActionSheets were designed for a very simple and constrained purpose, leaving lots of work for customization.

Comment: Dang I wish there was an easier way, I would use a custom action sheet but thats means I would have to recode a lot of things!