# Formatting buttons in the Master side of the split view controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller

I am creating a split view controller and it seems like I can't change the color of the buttons in the master view (they are white by default). I'd rather not create my own custom buttons so I was wondering if there was a way to do this programmatically? We tried to set the background of the UIColor but it changed the background color behind the button. Here's what it looks like:

[image: button]

Comment: Have you changed Button type to custom?

Comment: I tried that but the button is no longer a round rectangle button. Instead it is square and flat. if we could code the custom button to be a round rectangle then I guess that'd work too..

Comment: check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372731/how-can-i-set-a-button-background-color-on-iphone

Comment: thanks for the link. And for making me realize it's going to be way more complicated than I thought :)